# Saignant, à point, bien cuit ?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, alimentation

Si on comprend facilement « saignant » et « bien cuit », je me demandais à quoi faisait référence « à point ». Cuire à point ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En effet, on dit "à point" comme raccourci pour "cuit à point".

On peut trouver [là](http://blog.deluxe.fr/trucs-astuces-et-elements-de-choix/degres-de-cuisson-des-viandes-rouges.html) une description des degrés de cuisson des viandes rouges.

Comment: Mais le terme "point"... Il vient d'où ? De quel point s'agit-il ?

Comment: Il s'agit probablement du *point de cuisson* ! Plus sérieusement, et techniquement parlant, la cuisson est dite *à point* quand on retire la pièce de viande du feu au moment précis où le sang commence à suinter hors du morceau. Le choix de l'appellation *à point* révèle surtout que les cuisiniers à l'origine de l'appellation considéraient que c'était la cuisson "parfaite". Donc autant les termes *saignant* ou *bleu* sont factuels et descriptifs, autant *à point* ou *bien cuit* sont finalement plutôt issus de jugements de valeur, même s'ils ont pris ensuite une valeur de convention.

Answer (score 9):

Comme le dit [subtenante](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1296), *à point* est un raccourci pour *cuit à point*, mais le contexte rend souvent (pas toujours, voir son commentaire) l'utilisation explicite de *cuit* totalement superflue.

En effet, l'expression *à point* seule ne se limite pas à la cuisson de viandes mais est utilisée de manière générale pour signifier que quelque chose est « [Exactement comme il faut, au degré qui convient.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/point/substantif) » (chercher *steack*).

L'[étymologie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/point/substantif) de l'expression *à point* fait remonter l'usage général à 1245 et la qualification de la viande à 1668 — même si on estime que tout cela est trop vieux que pour avoir des certitudes, on peut raisonnablement penser qu'*à point* était utilisé de manière générale bien avant de l'être aussi pour la viande.

A priori, les autres stades de cuisson pour la viande ne seraient apparus que par la suite ; il ne faut donc à mon avis pas voir *à point* comme une exception mais comme la base, ou la norme. Les autres cuissons étant elles spécifiques à la viande ont revêtu des noms plus appropriés.

Comment: En effet, *à point* a un sens général indépendant du contexte. Mais même si *à point* pré-existait à l'utilisation culinaire pour les cuissons de viande, de même *saignant* et *bleu*... Il faut donc se rapporter au cas d'utilisation, et rien n'est *à point* hors d'un certain contexte. Sans le contexte de cuisson, ce pourraient être la découpe, la texture, la salaison, la présentation dans l'assiette, etc. qui soient à point... L'utilisation de *cuit* est en effet rendue superflue par le contexte seulement, mais ce n'est pas «alternativement» !

Comment: La cuisson dans le cas d'une viande est quand même le contexte par défaut. Si tu dis que tu as _mangé un steack à point_, personne ne va croire que tu dis qu'il était parfaitement découpé. Pour l'« alternativement », je t'accorde qu'il est plutôt déplacé et je l'enlève.

Comment: Je conteste. Si je demandais à un ami, à qui je fais à manger, "comment était le steak ?", et qu'il me répond "à point !", je le prendrais comme un synonyme de "très bon !" (doublé d'un jeu de mot qui me ravirait même si je l'ai pertinemment cuit saignant), non comme une description technique de sa cuisson. La cuisson n'est donc pas le contexte par défaut pour "à point".

Comment: Il ne me reste qu'à m'incliner.

Comment: +1, on peut aussi citer le proverbe "Tout vient à point à qui sait attendre" renforçant l'idée que à point a une signification plus générale.